# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.myapp'

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have prior experience with Django but have never run into such an error before. While trying to import my app module into urls.py of settings to add path. I am getting the above error. I have tried for solutions about relative imports but I am not able to fix it. My project structure is as follows:

```
> mysite
       mysite
           __init__.py
           asgi.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
       myapp
          >migrations
           __init__.py
           admin.py
           models.py
           tests.py
           views.py
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mysite.myapp.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
]
```

Error log:

```
 from mysite.personal.views import home
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.myapp'
```

Comment: Include error log and URLs.py code

Comment: @Pavankumar added urls.py and error log.

Comment: What is personal you in mysite.personal may I know what refers to it

Comment: @Pavankumar ignore it. It actually is the name of my app, let's use myapp for the sake for ease of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here mysite is the main directory and main app name so you don't need to mention in your import
Just you below impy code

```
from myapp.views import home
```

Don't forget to add your app in to installed apps

Comment: Have already tried that. It didn't work. Already added myapp to installed apps in settings.py

Comment: Can you post the error log after importing like above code

Comment: The code won't run. Getting 'unresolved reference 'myapp' ' in IDE.